# Count number of digits in a string, then create new column with counts in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, twitter

I have a pandas dataframe with a column that contains strings of Twitter screennames e.g. 'JohnDoe2719'. I want to count the amount of numbers in each user name e.g. 4, and then create a new column in my pandas dataframe with the counts for each screenname.

Some help in this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) with `'\d'` as regex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['JohnDoe2719', 'JohnDoe123', 'JohnDoe']})

df['count'] = df['name'].str.count(r'\d')
```

output:

```
          name  count
0  JohnDoe2719      4
1   JohnDoe123      3
2      JohnDoe      0
```