# Pandas - compute the sum of numerical characters of every string in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column "dname". It contains many rows of 2LD domain names. i.e.

```
123ask
example92
what3ver
...
```

I want to find the number of digits for every string in every row.

```
6
11
3
...
```

So, to create a new column in the dataframe with values i.e.

I have:

```
 df['numeric'] = df.dname.apply(lambda v : sum(x, x.isdigit() for x in v))
```

Is not work (
Any help ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count number of digits in a string, then create new column with counts in Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72187146/count-number-of-digits-in-a-string-then-create-new-column-with-counts-in-pandas)

Comment: @r-log it's not the same, here OP wants to compute 1+2+3 / 9+2 / 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your approach:

```
df['numeric'] = [sum(int(x) for x in s if x.isnumeric())
                 for s in df['dname']]

# or
df['numeric'] = df['dname'].apply(lambda s: sum(int(x) for x in s
                                                if x.isnumeric()))
```

You can also [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) digits, then convert to integer and [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html):

```
df['numeric'] = (df['dname'].str.extractall(r'(\d)')[0]
                 .astype(int).groupby(level=0).sum()
                )
```

Output:

```
       dname  numeric
0     123ask        6
1  example92       11
2   what3ver        3
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! Amazingly short program code.

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

```
import pandas as pd

def summ(n):
    sum1=0
    while n>0:
        sum1=sum1+(n%10)
        n=int(n/10)
    
    return sum1

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['dname'] = ['123ask','example92','what3ver']
list1=[]
for s in df['dname']:
    ss=''
    for b in s:
        if ((ord(b)>=48 and ord(b)<=57)):
            ss=ss+b;
    list1.append(ss)

df['digits']=list1
print(df)        
df['sum1'] = [ summ(int(a)) for a in df['digits']]

print(df)
```

output:

```
       dname digits  sum1
0     123ask    123     6
1  example92     92    11
2   what3ver      3     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
df['sum'] = (df['dname'].str.replace('\D', '', regex=True)
             .map(lambda x: sum(map(int, x))))
```

---

Yet another possible solution:

```
df['sum'] = (df['dname'].str.split('', expand=True)
             .map(lambda x: int(x) if x is not None and x.isnumeric() 
                  else int(0)).sum(axis=1))
```

---

Alternatively:

```
df['sum'] = (df['dname'].str.replace('\D', '', regex=True)
             .str.split('').map(
                 lambda x: sum([int(y) for y in x if y != ''])))
```

Output:

```
       dname  sum
0     123ask    6
1  example92   11
2   what3ver    3
```